# Dendrograms in R of data that is already categorized in R

Tags: r, text, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I already have text data that is categorized like what is shown below:

```
main_category   sub_category_level1 sub_category_level2
plants  fruit   apples
plants  fruit   oranges
plants  fruit   
plants  veggies carrots
plants  veggies 
plants  veggies onions
```

Most of the tutorials I've read online calculate a distance matrix, and then use the hclust function to cluster the data, but my data is already characterized and it's purely text data.

I'm also unsure of how to handle missing values.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just going to use igraph in R.

Comment: If you decided you don't like the question you asked, you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Dendrograms, by definition, need a *height*, i.e. a similarity value.

What you are looking for is a **tree**. Where the root splits at the main category, the branches then at the subcategory, etc.